# How Do I SELECT matched Values Of Session user to the unsession user In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got two `table` one is `student` and another is `teacher` So Basically I want a Select Query for this to table such that If certain teacher teaches for Comp Sci Department and this record is saved in `teacher` table under `department` column and in another case certain student also studies in same department and his record is also saved in `student` table under `department` column So my question, i only want teacher to be selected whose department is equal to the login user

Table `student`

```
    studentID   department
        1        Comp Sci
        2        Mech Engg
```

Table `teacher`

```
    teacherID   department   name
        1        Comp Sci     XYZ
        2        Mech Engg    ABC
```

In My Code it only selects the matched value from both table and i dont want this i dont know how to do that

```
<?php 
      $sql=("SELECT * 
             FROM student 
                 LEFT JOIN teacher ON student.studentID=teacher .teacher ID 
             WHERE student.department=teacher .department  "); 
            $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            while($admin=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo $admin['name'];
            echo $admin['department'];
            ?>
```

Comment: The `teachersID` has got NOTHING TO DO with the `studentID`

Comment: Hmmm I got that now Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    teacher 
INNER JOIN 
    student 
ON 
    student.department = teacher.department 
WHERE 
    student.studentID = $loginid // $login is the id of currently logged in student
```

Comment: Thanks Mate It Worked For Mi Thank You Very Much @jonju                SOF IS BEST EVER PLACE I GET TO LEARNED

Comment: Most Welcome!! Glad it helped